# MapReduce logs in Intellij idea console

Tags: intellij-idea, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am running WordCount MapReduce job in IntellijIdea but I could not see any logs in the Intellij console. if I run the same job in the Cloudera VM, I can see all the logs on the console.

Comment: have you added core-site and yarn-site etc in classpath?

Comment: @SouravGulati Thanks a lot!!! It worked. Can you please write it as answer so that i can accept it and also can you please provide some explanation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add core-site and yarn-site etc in your classpath. When you run map reduce from your IDE, it needs to know which cluster to connect to which only these conf files specify.